# Can I have Trello List in two Boards

Tags: trello, list

The copy cards from one board to an other workflow takes so many clicks and breaks the board and card metaphor.

Therefore I would like to have one and the same List in Multiple boards. I could simply drag and drop the card to that list, and it would appear in the other board.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible, but there is [a similar idea on the Trello Development board](https://trello.com/c/wAvC33zi/1249-cards-live-on-multiple-boards). They are currently accepting ideas and feedback.